# How to generate xml from SQL with Column Name as prop and Column Value as value MSSQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a SQL Table which has the following columns

1. **Name**
2. **FatherName**
3. **MotherName**
4. **Nationality**

I want to generate a XML by SQL Query Which will results as follows

```
<Customer>
<Prop ID="Name" ValStr="CustName" />
<Prop ID="FatherName" ValStr="Mr.xxx" />
<Prop ID="MotherName" ValStr="Mrs.yyy" />
<Prop ID="Nationality" ValStr="ZZZ" />
</Customer>
```

How can I get this. Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(Name VARCHAR(100),FatherName VARCHAR(100),MotherName VARCHAR(100),Nationality VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Name1','FatherName1','MotherName1','Nationality1')
,('Name2','FatherName2','MotherName2','Nationality2');

SELECT 
    'Name' AS [Prop/@ID]
   ,Name AS [Prop/@ValStr]
   ,''
   ,'FatherName' AS [Prop/@ID]
   ,FatherName AS [Prop/@ValStr]
   ,''
   ,'MotherName' AS [Prop/@ID]
   ,MotherName AS [Prop/@ValStr]
   ,''
   ,'Nationality' AS [Prop/@ID]
   ,Nationality AS [Prop/@ValStr]
FROM @tbl
FOR XML PATH('Customer'),ROOT('root')
```

The result

```
<root>
  <Customer>
    <Prop ID="Name" ValStr="Name1" />
    <Prop ID="FatherName" ValStr="FatherName1" />
    <Prop ID="MotherName" ValStr="MotherName1" />
    <Prop ID="Nationality" ValStr="Nationality1" />
  </Customer>
  <Customer>
    <Prop ID="Name" ValStr="Name2" />
    <Prop ID="FatherName" ValStr="FatherName2" />
    <Prop ID="MotherName" ValStr="MotherName2" />
    <Prop ID="Nationality" ValStr="Nationality2" />
  </Customer>
</root>
```

The *empty columns (`,''`)* are needed to tell the engine to start a new element. Otherwise you'd get an error, because an attribute cannot live twice within the same element.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,
 You can use **FOR XML RAW** utility

```
SELECT NAME, FATHERNAME, MOTHERNAME, NATIONALITY
FROM table_name 
FOR XML RAW ('ID');
```